# Нужен совет для начинающего в Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот недавно начала изучать Java Script, порекомендуйте книги или разные ресурсы, видео которые помогли вам в свое время освоить базу, буду рада полезным советам или лайфхакам.

Comment: Классный учебник (сам начал отсюда) https://learn.javascript.ru

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал, приходя на ресурс, вначале воспользоваться поиском по нему на наличие подобных тем.

Answer (score -1):

Почитать можно "Разработка на JavaScript" от издательства O'REILY (ISBN:978-5-4461-1462-7)
Попрактиковаться можно на https://www.codewars.com

Comment: Спасибо за ваш совет обязательно почитаю  книгу